# wso2 mutual ssl curl command APIM 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I tried setup ALLINONE in my local, followed the documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-mutual-ssl/
it worked, but what will be the curl command for request because the document talks about testing only through postman

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following curl commands when you want to use the header-based approach.

```
curl -X GET -H "X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE: (Base64 encoded public cert)" "https://localhost:8243/mock/v1" -v


curl -X GET -H "X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE: (Base64 encoded public cert)" "http://localhost:8280/mock/v1" -v
```

In order to work this, you need to add the following configuration to the deployment.toml in wso2am-3.2.0/repository/conf location.

```
[apimgt.mutual_ssl]
enable_client_validation = false
```

You can use the following curl commands if you are using the cert and key.

```
curl -k --cert int.ext.wso2.com.crt --key int.ext.wso2.com.key -X GET "https://localhost:8243/mock/v1" -v
```

Comment: getting error WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca in gateway logs and after running command we get error SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html Although certificate is not selfsigned

Comment: dont we need to pass key with cert

Comment: I thought you are looking for the header based approach. I updated my answer with key and cert based curl command

Comment: Can u cross check whether you have the same cert in the client-truststore of APIM? I think the cert is wrong and that is why you get unknown cert

Comment: when i tried with first approach which you suggested, i have same certificate uploaded to api and same cert i am passing through curl , But getting below error...............>
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
} [5 bytes data]
      0* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host ****** left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)

Comment: X-WSO2-CLIENT-CERTIFICATE: (Base64 encoded public cert)--------- gateway is not reading this header, if I give the same certificate and the wrong certificate, in  both case, same mutual authentication error

Comment: i am getting below error now, any thoughts? ......................EBUG - wire HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 << "WWW-Authenticate: Mutual SSL realm="WSO2 API Manager" OAuth2 realm="WSO2 API Manager", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token expired"[\r][\n]"

06:56:32
[2020-12-08 04:56:32,979] WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem

06:56:35
[2020-12-08 04:56:35,294] WARN - SourceHandler I/O error: General SSLEngine problem